# Dojo Data Grid - custom row, not being defined by structure

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is it possible to add a custom row to my datagrid?

For example if I have a country list, I want all the countries with their attributes being displayed in a table. However, I want to add each continent name only once, like:

```
Continent1
Country 1 ... ... ...
Country 2 ... ... ...

Continent2
Country 3 ... ... ...
Country 4 ... ... ...

Continent3
Country 5 ... ... ...
Country 6 ... ... ...
```

I know I could define a structure with two rows in the header, but then the name of the continent would appear for every country.

(I don't want to do a country list, but just as an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at dojox.grid.TreeGrid

You can see an example similar to yours here:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_treegrid.html

(look at the third example labelled "dojox.grid.TreeGrid 2-Level (programmatic)")

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to implement a filter function for this?